# when X and Y are two different finite sets and of size |X| and |Y|, then the number of functions X → Y is |Y| ^ |X|.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

When $X$ and $Y$ are two different finite sets and of size $|X|$ and $|Y|$, then the number of functions $f : X \to Y$ is $|Y|^{|X|}$.
Can anyone help me with it's proof?

Comment: For every $x$ you have any $y$ so $(\text{number of }y)^{\text{number of }x}$. This is just combinatorics.

Comment: Have you tried (say) induction on the size $|X|$?

Comment: Oh, I get it. It's just combinatorics.

Answer (score 3):

A function $f:X\to Y$ is determined by the choice of each $f(x)$ as $x$ ranges over $X$. So given $x\in X$, how many choices are there for $f(x)$? And how many elements are in $X$?